# "That's your only friend that I've ever met." Why is this an impossible sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, dictionaries, restrictive-clauses, double-possessives

I read the following usage note in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*'s entry for "of":

> *Grammarians have sometimes condemned categorically the so-called double genitive construction, as in a friend of my father's; a book of
> mine.  The construction is well supported by literary precedent,
> however, and serves a useful purpose. Thus there is no substitute for
> the double genitive in a sentence such as "That's the only friend of
> yours that I've ever met",  since a sentence such as "That's your only
> friend that I've ever met" is obviously impossible.*

I cannot perceive the awkwardness in "That's your only friend that I've ever met". It is a restrictive relative clause, so I think it implies you have more than one friend. I think it means exactly the same thing with "That's the only friend of yours that I've ever met": Your have some friends, but that person is the only one that I've ever met.

---

Edited: Here is the link, with different information from my older edition.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=of

> *There are also cases in which the double genitive may be more elegant; for example, many speakers find such sentences as "That's
> your only friend that I've ever met" to be awkward or impossible, but
> rephrasing using the double genitive provides an acceptable
> alternative, as in "That's the only friend of yours that I've ever
> met."*

Comment: _That's your only friend_ implies that you have only one friend, which is obviously not the intended meaning.

Comment: I Googled that quote. Unless you can provide a link proving otherwise, it's not from *The American Heritage Dictionary of English Language*, a title that doesn't actually exist as the full name of *The American Heritage Dictionary* is *The American Heritage Dictionary of **the** English Language*. Rather, it's a quote used in only non-English sources, specifically texts written in various Asian languages for learners of English as a second language, which often convey wrong information, like has happened here since, for example, there's definitely nothing impossible about that second sentence.

Comment: I think there's gonna be scope for disagreement here. I don't know anything about the source being cited, but I'm quite happy to say ***That's your only friend that I've ever met*** is NOT A VALID CONSTRUCTION from my perspective. On the other hand, I'm sure there will be other native speakers who will accept it with little or no hesitation.

Comment: What a disgrace! Such an elegant and deep question went basically unanswered.

Comment: [Extended conversation at WordReference on this topic for the curious](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/double-genitive-friend-of-my-brothers.2221951/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot perceive the awkwardness in "That's your only friend that I've ever met".

Good. In informal modern English, there isn't any.

The placement of the genitives and clauses here is no more wrong than the admonisher using *that* instead of *whom* in their own 'model' sentence. You might then ask

> Why do they *think* it's impossible?

It's rough going for ELLs but the best treatment of some people's tendency to beclown themselves with overstatements like your quote was [David Foster Wallace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Foster_Wallace)'s "[Tense Present](https://harpers.org/wp-content/uploads/HarpersMagazine-2001-04-0070913.pdf)" for the April 2001 *Harper's*. In this particular case, Google won't show the text you quoted but they have it scanned and indexed. They lay credit/blame for your passage at the doorstep of the 1992 edition of the *American Heritage Dictionary* edited by Anne H. Soukhanov. Her own justification for being a SNOOT despite knowing better would be along the lines of

> ... you're basically studying a foreign dialect. This dialect is called Standard Written English... There are some otherwise smart English profs who aren't very aware that there are real dialects of English other than SWE, so when they're reading your papers they'll put, like, "Incorrect conjugation" or "Comma needed" instead of "SWE conjugates this verb differently" or "SWE calls for a comma here." That's the good news—it's not that you're a bad writer, it's that you haven't learned the special rules of the dialect they want you to write in.

Still, [even though Ms Soukhanov is an intelligent woman](https://legacy.npr.org/programs/morning/features/1999/990817.dictionary.html), in this case she isn't defending good grammar or logic against the careless hordes. She is choosing to understand the sentence in a particularly unhelpful way, then declaring that way completely wrong, and then ignoring the *other* ways to understand the expression that make it perfectly clear to native speakers.

**She is taking the sentence to be the conjunction of the ideas** ***That is your only friend*** *and also* ***that is the only one of your friends whom I've met***. Those two ideas are mutually exclusive. Subsequent editions of the *AHD* and their [*Book of English Usage*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=BEHFyMCdwssC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA26) have walked back her claim a little. They now just say it's ungrammatical or that *some* people will find it ungrammatical. Really, of course, the way she (and some of the posters here) are choosing to misread the sentence is itself a mistake that tries to reuse the *only* for two separate meanings at the same time.

Like you already know, **that sentence actually just means** ***That is the only one of your friends whom I have met*** and there's no problem... unless you're doing a test with subjective grading and need to keep the scorer happy. In that case, the safer thing to do is rephrase.

(In Ms Soukhanov's defense, she was somewhat distracted. In this passage, she was trying to *defend* a good informal usage against people even *more* proscriptivist than she is, who want to pretend double genitives are never appropriate. She then tried to draw her own line to show she wasn't on the side of complete descriptivist chaos. I agree with you that her example wasn't well considered. Even [Astralbee above](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/337831/52137) thinks the sentence is a possible idea; they just dislike the sloppiness of using a restrictive clause on someone just described as totally unique.)

Comment: The answer that the OP wants to hear always gets the tick. And there's nothing they want to hear more than their English teacher is wrong.

Comment: Might be wrong but I don't think Ms Soukhanov was the OP's English teacher or that that's the only difference in our answers.

Comment: This is wrong. "Your only friend that I haven't met" is awkward. After "your only...", we expect a type of thing that people have, but instead we get "friend that I haven't met", which isn't a thing unto itself. People have friends, and some of those friends we haven't met, but people don't have a list of "friends that we haven't met".

Comment: @gotube Ignoring the checkmark and other voters who disagree, even on your own terms, your comment is mistaken. Of course _I_ don't have a list of [somehow isolated from humanity] entities-known-as-friends _we_ haven't met. On the other hand, _you_ (assuming we knew each other) _do_ have a list of _my_ friends who _you_ haven't met... and of course that's exactly what we're talking about. You can prefer another structure as less potentially awkward or less garden-pathy but it is _a_ valid way of expressing the concept.

Comment: @Astralbee hahaha, the first comment of yours is exactly what I want to hear the most.

Comment: You're not helping... xD

Comment: Congratulations on your detailed and well-researched answer!  Although the construction *does* sound very awkward to me, it would appear that not everyone shares that opinion (I was surprised to see the Ngram results Ben Murphy linked!). I have awarded this answer the bounty because SE doesn't allow it to be split, and although the competing answer gives a better analysis of what makes the 'impossible' construction sound wrong, your answer in my opinion is better at addressing the more directly relevant issue of whether it's actually *logically impossible* - and you've convinced me it isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by an 'impossible sentence'. It's always possible to be wrong! And it is poor English grammar. Here's why...

"That" introduces a *defining clause* - information that defines the subject. For example, if you spoke to someone about "*the friend*" they may not know who you are speaking about. Which friend? But, if you said "*the friend that I made on vacation*", that helps define which friend you mean.

"Your only friend" does not need any further definition. If someone has only one friend, that's all you need to know. Of course, that isn't what you mean to say, but that is what it sounds like. So, "*your only friend **that**...*" doesn't sound right from the start.

Opening with "***The** only friend...*" begs further definition. There are lots of friends in the world. Which friend? **Whose** friend? So you add more information:

> The only friend *of yours*...

"Of" means 'from among'. So we're talking about one specific friend (hence the definite article) from among a person's friends. But we still need something to define them to know what makes them the 'only' friend from among that group that we are speaking about.

> The only friend of yours *that I have met*.

And that's the friend defined. I've only met one of your many friends, and that's the one we're speaking about.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question, which is why the other form is “impossible”. I think this question is unanswerable because it’s obviously not impossible. As a native speaker, I see no problem with “That’s your only friend that I’ve ever met”: it’s a little awkward, but changing the words slightly, I’d prefer “That’s your only child that plays football” to “That’s the only child of yours that plays football”, which is more awkward.

Comment: NGrams also seems to imply that the so called “impossible” construction is more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your+only+_NOUN_+that%2Conly+_NOUN_+of+yours+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @BenMurphy Sorry you feel that way. I haven't actually said that "it's impossible"... just that it doesn't sound right, which it doesn't. From reading these kinds of questions on here it seems that non-native teachers of English sometimes take a harder line on 'rules'. I stand by my answer regardless of your downvote because I've answered why the OP is being told it is incorrect. You are taking a different kind of hard-line - insisting that it 'could' be used, but with the outcome of leaving an English learner sounding like they can't speak the language properly.

Comment: But why are you saying it doesn’t sound right? It sounds fine to me. As I pointed out in my second comment, it appears to be the more common form. So if someone uses it they’ll sound like any other speaker. What’s the problem?

Comment: @BenMurphy Why doesn't it sound right? I refer you to my answer. It's bad English grammar. Some people might say it in extemporaneous speech and some listeners might turn a blind eye to it, but that doesn't make it correct. Even Grammarly doesn't like it.

Comment: @BenMurphy Also, I've looked at the ngram results you linked to and they are seriously flawed. For example, it is including results where a sentence ends with "your only friend" and the next sentence begins with "That", because the search ignores punctuation.

Comment: But it finds no results for "only friend of yours that", so that's not really an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146793/discussion-between-ben-murphy-and-astralbee).

Comment: @BenMurphy Exactly - ngrams prove nothing. They are based on a limited selection of books available in Google Books. We've had discussions on meta about how answers that rely on ngrams alone are not really satisfactory answers. Ngrams are okay for finding well-known idioms but there's no guarantee that every given sentence you could compose in this very flexible language will be found in this relatively tiny selection of (mainly old and out of copyright) literature.

Comment: "They are based on a limited selection of books" How limited is that? A science paper supplies that figure: [*While the tool’s massive corpus of data [(about 8 million books or 6% of all books ever published)](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0213554#:~:text=While%20the%20tool's%20massive%20corpus,of%20results%20have%20simultaneously%20emerged.) has been used in various scientific studies, concerns about the accuracy of results have simultaneously emerged*"

Comment: @Mari-LouA As you said - 6% of published books. And while that 6% is a lot of books numerically speaking, it's still a "limited selection". But the main problem is the selection criteria - what makes a book part of that 6%? It is mainly books that are so old they are out of copyright (no good for comparing modern English) or books that were in the public domain anyway (not good enough to be published). Many are not scholarly and have not been professionally edited.

Comment: The actual main problem is just bad optical recognition. Anything older than about 1800 and you're as likely to get filver or siluer or liliier as silver. Even so it's a huge quantity and the original point wasn't well taken. @BenMurphy is right that in terms of actual usage _both_ the original source and the way you're parsing it are somewhere between completely wrong and gatekeeping.

Comment: It's perfectly fine English grammar!

Comment: I 100% agree with your analysis of why the 'impossible' construction *sounds* wrong (which to me at least it *does*) and about how the double genitive rephrasing improves the sentence.  But, the really interesting part of the original question (the reason for starting the bounty on it) was 'what would justify calling it **impossible**.'  I believe that the competing answer's analysis of how logically, it *shouldn't* be considered impossible (and especially the supporting fact that OP's reference has been since updated to change that phrasing) better addresses that aspect of the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I gave both answers +1 and would have split the bounty if that were possible